# HTML, JS, CSS Engines

Tags: web-development, c++

I am just messing around, trying to figure out how stuff works and right now I have a couple questions about HTML, JS and CSS engines.

I know there are two major JavaScript engines out there - V8 and JavaScriptCore (WebKit's JS engine as far as I know). Is that correct? And what are the main HTML + CSS renderers out there? Let's say I want to build a web browser using V8 (I saw it has some documentation and stuff + I like the way it works), what are the best options for me?

Partially another question. Is there any bare browser that uses V8 and runs on Ubuntu at least?

P.S. I am a Ubuntu user and prefer C++.

Comment: Can you provide link to the documentation you reference?

Comment: What so you mean by "bare browser"?

Comment: @ysdx, Browser without much functionality except JS, HTML and CSS engine.

Comment: @ClintNash, I was talking about the menu option 'Documentation' in https://developers.google.com/v8/

Comment: I believe [Uzbl](http://uzbl.org/) is <del>exactly</del> what you're looking for - bare Webkit, though with JavaScriptCore, not V8.

Comment: Thanks for sharing doc: "This document is intended for C++ programmers who want to embed the V8 JavaScript engine within a C++ application." Sounds awesome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JS engines [1, 2]:

- v8
- JavaScriptCore/SquirrelFish
- SpiderMonkey (Mozilla, C++)
- Rhino (Mozilla, Java)
- Tamarin (Flash)
- Chakra (IE9; not open source)

Rendering Engines:

- Webkit
- Gecko (Mozilla)
- Presto (Opera, not open source, not usable standalone)
- Trident (IE9)

A quite simple option would be to use Webkit as a rendering engine as it quite
widely used in many different projects. Chrome/chromium is using v8 and runs on Ubuntu.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines

Comment: I can see there is WebKit as well as GTK-WebKit (which is a GTK+ port). What does WebKit use for visualizing rendering's results?

Comment: AFAI understand, you have core Webkit which is unconnected from any kind of UI/system layer. Then you have different bindings/ports for different UI libs/systems: Apple Cocoa, Qt, GTK …

Comment: Tamarin is an ActionScript, not JavaScript engine.

Comment: @dude: ActionScript is a dialect of ECMAScript (just like JavaScript is). What's more, few years ago, it was expected to be used in Mozilla applications as its EcmaScript engine.

Comment: So, what does Webkit do apart giving you access to DOM library and stuff if it doesn't do rendering?

Comment: WebCore is the (C++) core of WebKit (Source/WebCore in the SVN http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk). It has code for : DOM tree, HTML/XML/CSS parsing, SVG/MathML/HTML rendering ... It does the actual rendering but The Webkit/ subdirectories contains the different "ports", bindings for languages/APIs/toolits/systems (blackberry, chromium, GTK, Mac/Cocoa, Qt, wx).

Comment: What the ports do (AFAIU) is : bind a JavaScript engine (JavaScriptCore, v8 …), provide some "UI/interface" related features which are left abstract in WebCore (windows, clicks, keyboard inputs … which are handled by the UI technology : Qt, Coca, GTK …).

Comment: Though part of that stuff is in WebCore/platform. So … I don't know exactly which parts are in WebCore are which parts are not.

Answer (score -2):

Have you checked out [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)? I only mention it because it fits your tech-trifecta: 1. JS, HTML, CSS  2. V8 3. and C++.

Not sure about building browsers, or rendering in particular.... [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) gives a great history of the browser wars of 2010, as far as V8 goes. Names get crazy like SpiderMonkey, Rhino, and IE... may be an interesting history .

Comment: Isn't NodeJS just a JS engine build on top of V8?